# How to clear dropped items with console command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-tekkit

I'm running a small tekkit classic server with a few friends and I made an EMC farm that admittedly works too well. After turning off the server and coming back on the next day, it's horrendously laggy. I know it's the machine that's creating too many entities but it's so laggy I can hardly make it to the machine to break it and wait for the items to de-spawn. Unless I stop it, there will be no chance to turn off the machine. Is there any console command I should know about with the tekkit classic server commands, or what can I do? (P.S. There are more entities spawning than de-spawn so waiting it out won't work.)

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed?

Answer (score 2):

If you are in 1.8+, you can also use vanilla commands:

```
/kill @e[type=Item,r=500]
```

r is the radius. @e is entity.

Comment: The version I'm running from technicpack is 3.1.2, a dumb question but will that still work?

Comment: When typed into the cmd it just says that I can only perform this command as a player.

Comment: Well, you can't type it into the server-prompt, if that's what you are asking. there are methods to do this, but i don't know them. the radius is evaluated based on your current position, so to use it you must be ingame. However, you could use a clocked commandblock, which will perform just as well :)
and as long as your Minecraft version is 1.8 or beyond, it will work. I don't know which Minecraft versions are supported by tekkit 3.1.2, but if you press F3 ingame and look in the top left corner, it will give you your MC version.

Answer (score 1):

With WorldEdit, you can remove dropped items with the command /remove items (radius)
Hope that helps you in solving your problem.

Comment: Unknown command when I put it in the console or in chat ( I am an OP too )